# jQuery - change table row color on hover, getting hover events to work

Tags: jquery

I want to highlight a table row by changing its color, using jQuery.  Have RTFM'd, experimented and researched extensively with little luck.

HTML:

```
<table id="waypointsTable" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>some text</td>
</tr> ...
```

javascript:

```
$('#waypointsTable > tbody > tr > td').hover(function() {
    alert(1);
}, function() {
    alert(2);
});
```

At this point I'm just trying to get the hover functions to fire.  Should hover be tied to the tr or the td? Do I always have to include the tbody reference when selecting table rows and td's?  Is it better to put a class on each tr or td instead of the above approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want it to trigger for each row or for each cell?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Looks fine for the most part, if you want to trigger for each row, you can bind to the tr directly.

just:

```
$('#waypointsTable tr').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

(full code at http://jsfiddle.net/nicholasstephan/8nbVG/)

should work...

For this case specifically, using a css :hover pseudo selector would do the job too.

```
#waypointsTable tr:hover {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Omitting the '>' descendant operator thingy, as you did, made my code work.  Also I was seeking a better pattern for highlighting the rows -- I had been using jQuery css function with limited success.

Answer (score 6):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("tr").not(':first').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).css("background","yellow");
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).css("background","");
  }
);

</script>
```

[Demo](http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/jQuery/jQuery-highlight-table-row-record.html)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the color of the row when it's hovered over, then put the :hover on the row itself. However, note that rows themselves can't have background colors, only cells, so in CSS terms, you'd need this:

```
tr td { background: normal background style here }
tr:hover td { background: hovered background style here}
```

Comment: adding background colors to TRs is only a problem in IE. see http://mashable.com/2009/07/16/ie6-must-die/ and http://ie8-must-die.com/.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to trigger the event for future added rows you could use

```
$("#table_id").on("mouseover", 'tr' function () {
    //stuff to do on mouseover
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
   $('#waypointsTable tr').hover(function() {
          $(this).toggleClass('hover');
    });
```

css style

```
.hover {
    background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some useful links.For **more reference and demo** see the below link.

[jQuery Change table row color on hover, getting hover events to work](http://www.thedevelopertips.com/JQuery/JQuery/HighLight-TableRow-JQuery.aspx?id=55)

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $("tr:not(:has(th))").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
    });
    $("tr:not(:has(th))").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
  .hover
    {
        background-color: #81B441;
    }
```

HTML :

```
<table class="tblBorder" border='1'>
<tr class="hover"><th>No</th><th>Page Name</th><th>No of View</th><th>Comments</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Java Script</td><td>28</td><td>10</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>CSS</td><td>29</td><td>78</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will add and remove the css, but this will not do this for the top table row. e.g. your heading row.

```
$("#waypointsTable tr").not(':first').hover(function(){
 $(this).addClass("tr-hover");
   },function(){
    $(this).removeClass("tr-hover");
   }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but try putting a div with either a class or id inside the  and see if that helps.